# AES or cryptobox() for authenticated encryption

Tags: aes

I need to encrypt some packets on a constrained hardware.

I was enthusiast about the NaCl suit, since Chacha/Salsa20 is a nice and fast symmetric cipher algorithm when no AES-NI instructions is available.
But I discovered that poly1305 (the authentication layer) is based on AES!

Why? If I plan to use cryptobox it's because there is no AES; but if AES is available in hardware, may I prefer AES-GCM?

What is the logic behind this? Why poly1305-AES and not poly1305-Salsa20?

Comment: Are you _sure_ that NaCl uses poly-1305 with AES and not with Salsa20?

Comment: indeed i can't prove it, since the initial paper was about poly1305-AES, I guessed NaCl did use it... I may be wrong... (it may use xsalsa20 according to this : https://cr.yp.to/highspeed/naclcrypto-20090310.pdf)

Comment: From the [website](https://nacl.cr.yp.to/box.html): `crypto_box` is `curve25519xsalsa20poly1305`, a particular combination of Curve25519, Salsa20, and Poly1305 specified in [Cryptography in NaCl](https://cr.yp.to/highspeed/naclcrypto-20090310.pdf). `crypto_secretbox` is `crypto_secretbox_xsalsa20poly1305`, a particular combination of Salsa20 and Poly1305.

Answer (score 4):

> Why poly1305-AES and not poly1305-Salsa20?

You misunderstand. Poly1305-AES has always been [defined](https://cr.yp.to/mac/poly1305-20050329.pdf) in terms of an underlying Poly1305 function combined with AES:

> $\text{Poly1305}_r(m, \text{AES}_k(n))$, the Poly1305-AES authenticator of a message $m$ with nonce $n$ under secret key $(k, r)$, is defined as the 16-byte unsigned little-endian representation of $$\left(\left(\left(c_{1}r^q + c_{2}r^{q−1} + \cdots + c_{q}r^1\right) \text{mod } 2^{130} − 5\right) + \text{AES}_k(n)\right) \text{mod } 2^{128}$$ *[definition of $c = f(m)$ omitted for brevity]*

As you can see, under this definition, AES is:

- Not being computed *inside of* the function; rather, its *output* is being *fed into* $\text{Poly1305}_r$ as an *argument*
- Trivially replaceable by any other cipher
- **Only being run on a single nonce, not the whole message**
- Clearly doing nothing but whitening this single per-message nonce anyway

So performance shouldn't be an issue. If you are on an embedded system with no dedicated cryptography instructions and need to do AEAD on a 10-gigabyte $m$, even a reference implementation of Poly1305-AES would only have to "inefficiently" crunch $n$ *once*. (This would become a problem when processing many individual messages; see below for why this isn't an issue in practice.)

---

The [IETF definition](https://datatracker.ietf.org/doc/html/draft-agl-tls-chacha20poly1305-00#section-4) of the underlying Poly1305 function doesn't even bother expressing whitening preferences against the nonce, instead just demanding a "one-time key" *per se*, and leaving it up to the caller to ensure uniqueness:

> Poly1305 takes a 32-byte, one-time key and a message and produces a 16-byte tag that authenticates the message such that an attacker has a negligible chance of producing a valid tag for a inauthentic message.
>
> The first 16 bytes of the one-time key form an integer, $r$, as follows: the top four bits of the bytes at indexes 3, 7, 11 and 15 are cleared, the bottom 2 bits of the bytes at indexes 4, 8 and 12 are cleared and the 16 bytes are taken as a little-endian value.
>
> An accumulator is set to zero and, for each chunk of 16 bytes from the input message, a byte with value $1$ is appended and the 17 bytes are treated as a little-endian number. If the last chunk has less than 16 bytes then zero bytes are appended after the $1$ until there are 17 bytes.  The value is added to the accumulator and then the accumulator is multiplied by $r$, all $\text{mod } 2^{130} - 5$.
>
> Finally the last 16 bytes of the one-time key are treated as a little-endian number and added to the accumulator, $\text{mod } 2^{128}$. The result is serialised as a little-endian number, producing the 16 byte tag.

---

In fact, "in the real world", AES *is* generally replaced with the in-use stream cipher in non-AES AE(AD) constructions. Both [TLS’ `AEAD_CHACHA20_POLY1305`](https://datatracker.ietf.org/doc/html/rfc8439#section-2.8), and (relevantly to your question as-stated) [`crypto_box`’s default mode of x25519+ChaCha20-Poly1305](https://github.com/jedisct1/libsodium/blob/1.0.18/src/libsodium/crypto_aead/chacha20poly1305/sodium/aead_chacha20poly1305.c#L45) ([Libsodium’s documentation](https://libsodium.gitbook.io/doc/secret-key_cryptography/aead/chacha20-poly1305/original_chacha20-poly1305_construction)) internally use the message cipher’s hash function for preprocessing the nonce into the key for Poly1305.

So you aren't actually using AES for Poly1305 key preprocessing in this case (though, even if you were, it wouldn't actually be a performance issue; the only real threat would be its making your cryptosystem vulnerable to *two* different ciphers’ future breakages vs. just one).